# Ventana modal en Bootstrap se cierra sola automáticamente

Tags: jquery, html5, css, bootstrap, modal

Buenas, tengo un problema con las ventanas modales de `Bootstrap`, Esta se cierra sola al abrirla, pincho en el botón, la abro. y en menos de un segundo se cierra, y si no se cierra sola, al mover el ratón se cierra. Es muy raro.

Añado todo el código de la página para ver si algo entra en conflicto

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Galería de fotos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Añadir elemento a la galería</h1><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputNombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombre">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputNombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagen</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUrl" placeholder="URL">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Subir imagen</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aplicar cambios</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- modal -->
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCategoria" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoría</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" name="categoria">
                        <option value="opc" disabled selected>Seleccione una opción...</option>
                        <option value="materiales">Materiales</option>
                        <option value="montajes">Montajes</option>
                        <option value="videos">Videos</option>
                        <option value="equipamientodj">Equipamiento DJ</option>
                        <option value="escenarios">Escenarios</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAlt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alt</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código está funcionando bien, no se cierra como manifiesta en su pregunta,  quizá hay algo adicional que no muestra en el ejemplo que provoca el  cierre de la ventana modal.

Comment: Voy a poner todo el código de la página para ver si podéis localizar algo que interfiera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este comportamiento suele pasar cuando el `boton` que abre la ventana modal está dentro de un `form` ya que no se le asigna un `type` al `button`  **por defecto le da un type submit** según la documentación [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/button)   que es el motivo principal de su problema,  o cuando se cargan `Bootstrap.js and Modal.js` juntos , en su caso es la primera opción , para solucionar este inconveniente cambiar el `Button` por un `input type button`

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
  value="Upload" data-target="#myModal" />

<!--O Un type directamente a su etiqueta Button-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Gracias! funciona!

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
```

Colocale un tipo al boton, asi se arreglara, si tienes dudas comenta, Slds...

Comment: Gracias! funciona!